# Creating word document from a template using java

Tags: java, ms-word

I want to create a word document which has a text part, checkboxes and tables in it. I want to create a template of this document and use the template to create a word document using java.

Can anyone please suggest me an easiest way to do the same. I tried doing xml mapping but it only works fine with text and tables. I am more concerned about the checkboxes in the word document.

Please help!

Comment: Can you post some example code of what you've tried?

Comment: Theres not much of a coding iv done.. I have created a simple xml file for the word doc and replaced the placeholders in the xml with the values in my java program.

Comment: Have you looked at Apache POI? http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html

Comment: Apache poi does not provide anything for checkboxes..

Answer (score 0):

I had a play with a bound checkbox content control.

I found that Word updates the custom xml part when you check/uncheck the checkbox on the document surface, but that the checkbox doesn't automatically update when you change the value in the custom xml part outside word.  Nor is it enough to update the checked state (w14:checkbox/w14:checked) outside Word 2010: it seems to be ignored.

In other words, unlike for bound text content controls, the update isn't bi-directional.

So to make this work, you'd need to apply the binding yourself (ie alter the sdtContent to be a checked or unchecked box).

In terms of Java implementations, [docx4j 2.7.1](http://www.docx4java.org) can apply bindings for text content controls, but would need a minor patch to insert the checked or unchecked box.

Comment: Thanks Jason.. I am working on it. Can you provide a sample code or some links that can help me..

Answer (score -1):

[JDReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) and [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) might help you.  I think both can do what you require given the template requirement and output format.