# How to insert data into a Microsoft Word Template using Java?

Tags: java, ms-word, word-template

I have a map of data that I want to insert into fields in an existing Microsoft Word Template.  Preferably, I'd like to accomplish it using Java.  I extracted text from a pdf file and then parsed it for data.  Now, I need to figure out how to insert that data into a word template, which serves as a form.  By data, I mean things such as name, address, etc.

Is it even possible?  I haven't been able to locate any documentation or references that would help me with this task.  I've been able to find some stuff on creating MS Word documents, but nothing as far as insertion into template text fields.

Comment: Just Google: Java Word Template and you'll find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379580/how-to-open-and-manipulate-word-document-template-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732832/creating-word-document-from-a-template-using-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697224/creating-a-word-document-from-a-template-dynamically-using-values-from-java-obje http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715552/how-create-a-word-document-from-a-template-or-existing-document-with-java and so on...

Answer (score 3):

I've used [JWord](http://www.independentsoft.com/jword) several times to create documents from template. It's not free but accomplished what I needed.

Comment: It looks like a good product, but I'm doing this project as a favor to my employer.... so, I have no interest in spending money on top of my time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [ODFDOM](https://github.com/tdf/odftoolkit) project for ODF documents (LibreOffice, OpenOffice open document format, not Microsoft MOOXML format).

You can load an ODF document and modify variables inside it, style and content or you can create a document from scratch.

The project is quite active, the latest version available is 2014-06-02 - ODF Toolkit 0.6.1-incubating.

Comment: The requirement was specific to MS Word.

Comment: Ok, thought by "Microsoft Word Template" you meant a generic Microsoft style word document. Notice that you can always transform it into ODF and start from there.

Comment: This question is over two years old.  I've resolved it long time ago.

Comment: Maybe other people are still interested, otherwise we would delete all old and solved questions.

Comment: @B.K. Hi, how did you resolve the problem ?

Comment: @Hohenheim I don't recall.  It was almost three years ago, but I don't think it was hard.  It was even easier in C#.